# Ethernet port acts weird

Tags: ethernet-port

Friend has a Raspi 2, was installed with raspbian, but had ethernet issues. It wasn't configured at all, so after a few tries to fix it, I just loaded it up with a new Noobs Lite install. At boot it gives a problem that a wired ethernet connection is required, while the cable is plugged in.

The lights of the ethernet port don't blink or blink once, but very faded. After a while (2 minutes?) the lights both stay on, even after disconnecting the ethernet cable.

When I connect my pi to the cable they blink like you would expect it, so router/cable issues aren't the issue..

Is this a fried ethernet port?